# Since (past time) ... to (current time)?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, translation

I am trying to write a sentence that shows my experience as a cook; for example, since my first job at ABC, and then to DEF, to currently working at GHI, I have gain ...

Comment: It's not wrong, but do you know how resumes are read? They are not read, they are scanned ... if you are lucky. So is packing four parts into your sentence serving your purposes?

Comment: it's actually an application (1000 words) .. But is there a better way to frame this sentence?

Comment: I'd form 2 - 4 sentences. Short and sweet is stellar.

Comment: do you mind providing an example?

Comment: I'd separate A, D, and G into separate sentences. Then wrap that up in sentence four. It's not choppy, it's bold.

Comment: oh, I get what you mean. but I would like to summarize (or mention) all of these company in just one sentence. is it possible?

Comment: For a resume sometimes a table is better than sentences.

Comment: it's an application (1000 words), not resume

Comment: It is not only *possible* to cram all that into one sentence, you have. If you are attached to that idea and tied to it, it would be hard to help on your essay.

Comment: Welcome to the site. I imagine your question to have been marked down because it seems too simple for one of the erudite minds in this site, and because you do not show much evidence of your own research. I have moved it up again because we are here to help, particularly newcomers, and not to criticise negatively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Since my first job” refers to a time after the job ended, suggesting that you gained no experience in that job. Better to start with something like:

Since starting my first job at ABC I have worked at DEF and GHI, and have gained experience in ...

This is only one of many suggestions you may receive but it avoids the awkward start.

Comment: I have gained experience as a chef since my my first  at ABC, followed by similar stint in DEF and GHI. Could it be another option?